# UILabel change height, animation expands from center

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I'm trying to increase a labels height using animation, however the animation causes the label to first expand from the center, and then jump in place with the correct y point. This looks terrible. I would like only the bottom to expand.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{

   [self.about increaseHeightFromTopLeft:deltaHeight];

   [self.scrollView increaseContentHeight];

} completion:nil];


- (void)increaseHeightFromTopLeft:(CGFloat ) increased  {

    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.originX, self.originY, self.frameWidth, self.frameHeight + increased);

    self.frame = newFrame;
}
```

The label is called about, you can see a video of the animation here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcqktIZ9moY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: To my eye, the thing that needs animation are the buttons underneath.  The label's text itself is not an animatable property.  The label could start out large, partly covered by those buttons on a subview that they share, then you change the text in the label and slide the buttons

Comment: Although it was not the answer i was looking, i still did what you suggested and it looks good. Thx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Faced the same problem!
Try to set label's `contentMode` to `Top` in your code:

in Objective-C

```
label.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
```

In Swift:

```
label.contentMode = .top
```

Comment: Good question, good answer. He should've accepted your answer. You saved me a ton of time. Thanks.

Comment: Very good answer.  But if you prefer autolayout, you can set Content Mode in Attributes Inspector under View.  I set it to Top and it works as intended.

Comment: Nice answer thanks. I'm using Label -> Stack View -> TableViewCell and it works like a charm.